# how to update the original version of bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have the original version of Bitcoin-qt and have been trying to update as I cant access my wallet. It has been running for weeks but when my internet drops out, the process starts again. I there anyone in the Brisbane region who could assist sorting this out ?
Below are the details of the software

Bitcoin Core version v0.11.1 (32-bit)

Copyright (C) 2009-2015 The Bitcoin Core Developers

This is experimental software.

Distributed under the MIT software license, see the accompanying file COPYING or http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php.

This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit https://www.openssl.org/ and cryptographic software written by Eric Young and UPnP software written by Thomas Bernard.

Comment: Save a wallet backup, install a newer version, drop a copy of your wallet backup inside, try running the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/23.0/

> How to Upgrade
>
> If you are running an older version, shut it down. Wait until it has
> completely shut down (which might take a few minutes in some cases),
> then run the installer (on Windows) or just copy over
> /Applications/Bitcoin-Qt (on Mac) or bitcoind/bitcoin-qt (on Linux).
>
> Upgrading directly from a version of Bitcoin Core that has reached its
> EOL is possible, but it might take some time if the data directory
> needs to be migrated. Old wallet versions of Bitcoin Core are
> generally supported.

I would definitely make a wallet backup before doing this. At the least, make a copy of wallet.dat on a different computer and double check that it is a good copy (e.g. run a checksum program on it and compare with a checksum of the original).

Comment: Thank you, I will see how I go